# while accessing two different servlets one is available and the other is throwing servlet not found error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, model-view-controller, tomcat9

I am working on a student management project in which I created two servlets in same folder, `LoginController`  for handling the login and `TestContoller` for registering new student. The problem is that when I try to login LoginController is accessible and I am able to login but when i try to register a student through a `register.jsp` page mapped to TestController , I get `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found. The requested resource [/StudentManagement/TestController] is not available` error

Here is my code:-

register.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/TestController" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

TestController

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestController
 */
@WebServlet("/TestController")
public class TestController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TestController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("name"));
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you trying to access `TestController`? I do not see any problem with your code.

Comment: Yeah , there wasn't any problem with the code.There was problem with the server. The problem resolved after I removed the server and added it again.